# bigmemory/windows compatibility

Tags: windows, r, ehcache-bigmemory

Following on from this question([Can't install bigrf package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25239514/cant-install-bigrf-package/25239661?noredirect=1#comment39319962_25239661));
Is there a version of the bigmemory package, and by extension bigrf that works with windows OS?
I understand that support has been removed in recent years but I can't seem to find when that support was removed and thus which versions should still work with windows??
compatibility

Comment: [This comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18226970/how-to-install-bigmemory-and-bigfr-on-windows-os#comment26726042_18227281) suggests to use package `ff` instead.

Comment: With using ff, proximity=false and only 1000 trees I managed to get it to run. Thank you

Comment: Pascal, just browsing past questions and if you want to formalise your answer I can accept it. I realise it's been a year since this was asked but I thought I should offer